# Intellij unable to install Spark correctly

Tags: maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I've tried through the adding the dependencies through Maven and also tried opening the zip file from their site, but I keep getting the same error when I run the file

> SLF4J: Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

There are 2 SLF4J, api.1.7.13, and simple1.7.13. The `StaticLoggerBinder` does exists in the simple file, but for some reason intellij doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope maven side the artifacts are resolved. only intellij classpath its not recognized.... if so, you can do below...

```
cd <your project dir>
mvn idea:idea
```

Above command will download the project plugins for IntelliJ. And, above command will also create the project file (`.ipr`), module file (`.iml`) and workspace file (`.iws`).

Comment: After doing this maven had an error about the maven compiler which I fixed,  but then the file ran properly.Thanks!